# face a problem while calling constant is laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi every body i am working on a project of laravel I am facing a problem while calling constants in a view
here is the code of view

```php
{{Config::get('constants.site_name')}}
```

and here is code in constant that i created in config file of laravel

```php
return [
    
    'site_name'=>'My ECOM'

];
```

please help what is problem with my code or any other problem.

thanks

Comment: And the problem is...? You get an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: @El_Vanja Not name is not showing as i wrote is constant code (MY Ecom)

Comment: Do `php artisan config:cache` first and then try again.

Comment: @nice_dev thanks for helping it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The config file you're referring must have the name `constants.php` and must be located in the `config` directory.